# How to restrict the first row of the csv while importing into the database table

Tags: php

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?>
```

> IN the above import process the first row in the csv file also getting inserted into the database can any one help me how to restrict the first row while inserting HElp me soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lineNr = 1;
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0] && $lineNr!=1) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
            $lineNr++;
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

}
```

Comment: fclose() needed. And probably $data[0] is undefined for the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fgetcsv($handle);
if ( $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'") )
```

before

```
do{ ...
```

And do not forget to close the file with:

```
fclose( $handle );
```

before the redirect.